# How to show that $E(\lvert e^{itY_n}-e^{itc}\rvert)$ goes to $0$ where $Y_n\xrightarrow{p}c$

Tags: probability-theory, expected-value, characteristic-functions

I'm trying to prove this statement using Levy's theorem.

If $X_n\xrightarrow{d}X$ and $Y_n\xrightarrow{p} c$ then $X_n+Y_n\xrightarrow{d} X+c$

I have for the distance of the characteristic functions, which needs to go to $0$:
$$\begin{aligned}
\left\lvert E\left(e^{it(X_n+Y_n)}\right) - E\left(e^{it(X+c)}\right) \right\rvert
&\le \left\lvert E\left(e^{it(X_n+Y_n)}\right) - E\left(e^{it(X_n+c)}\right)\right\rvert + \left\lvert E\left(e^{it(X_n+c)}\right) - E\left(e^{it(X+c)}\right)\right\rvert \\
&=D_1 + D_2
\end{aligned}$$
Here $D_2$ vanishes somewhat trivially because $X_n\xrightarrow d X$. However I'm struggling with $D_1$. Using the triangle inequality we have
$$\begin{aligned}
\left\lvert E\left(e^{it(X_n+Y_n)}\right) - E\left(e^{it(X_n+c)}\right)\right\rvert
&=\left\lvert E\left(e^{it(X_n+Y_n)}-e^{it(X_n+c)}\right)\right\rvert\\
&\le E\left(\left\lvert e^{it(X_n+Y_n)}-e^{it(X_n+c)}\right\rvert\right)\\
&= E\left(\left\lvert e^{it(X_n)}\right\rvert\left\lvert e^{itY_n} - e^{itc}\right\rvert\right)\\
&= E\left(\left\lvert e^{itY_n} - e^{itc}\right\rvert\right)
\end{aligned}$$

How can we show that this goes to $0$?

Comment: If $Y_n \to c$ in probability then $Y_n \to c$ in distribution as well.

Comment: So? This means $\mathbb{E}[e^{itY_n}-e^{itc}] \to 0$. Here something stronger is needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

wlog $c=0$ (just multiply by $e^{-itc}$)

Now, fix $\epsilon>0$. For $n$ sufficiently big $\mathbb{P}(|Y_n|>\epsilon) < \epsilon$.

Thus, $\mathbb{E}[|e^{itY_n}-1|] \leq 2\epsilon + |e^{it\epsilon}-1|$ for any such $n$ (why?).

This means that $\limsup\limits_{n \to \infty} \mathbb{E}[e^{itY_n}-1|] = 0$ for any $t$ (even though the convergence "depends on $t$"), but I guess that's fine.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't see why where you said why, could you please say why?

Comment: I mean, that step is not trivial. It was just a "make sure you understand here"

Comment: $\mathbb{E}[|e^{itY_n}-1|] = \mathbb{E}[|e^{itY_n}-1|\chi_{|Y_n|>\epsilon}]+\mathbb{E}[|e^{itY_n}-1|\chi_{|Y_n|\leq\epsilon}] \leq 2 \mathbb{P}(|Y_n|>\epsilon) + |e^{it\epsilon}-1|\mathbb{P}(|Y_n|\leq\epsilon) \leq 2\epsilon + |e^{it\epsilon}-1|$

Comment: Oh wait, you deleted the comment asking for clarification, well I'll leave it here